# Constant $C$ in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have differential equations:

$$  dy + x(y+1)dx = 0.$$

I'm dividing boths sides by $(y+1)$:

$$ \frac{dy}{y+1} + xdx = 0.$$

The solution is:

$$ \ln|y+1| + \frac{x^{2}}{2}  = \ln |C|.$$

As we can see, I've assumed that arbitrary constant is $ \ln|C|.$

Next:

$$ \ln \left|\frac{y+1}{c}\right| = -\frac{x^{2}}{2} $$

$$ e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}} = \left|\frac{y+1}{c}\right| $$

$$ \pm e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}  = \frac{y+1}{c}.$$

Letting $d = \pm c,$

$$ d e^ \frac{-x^{2}}{2} = y+1 $$

$$ y = de^{-\frac{-x^2}{2}} -1 $$

Could I write additional note that  $C \neq  0$? Because $ \ln 0 $ doesn't exist right?

Comment: @Chinny84 I suggest you submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: You can directly proceed from the third equation to $y+1=C·e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$, there is no need to introduce the extra sign variations. $C=0$ gives the equally valid and regular constant solution $y=-1$ that had to be excluded for the separation approach.

Comment: @LutzL you are absolutely correct - Compounding one error with an arguably larger one! In any case cheers for the catch. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the method of separation of variables, you need to reduce the domain be the zero set of the divisor. This might lose some solutions so first check if curves in the zero set are solutions, which in this case the constant function $y\equiv -1$ is.

Then proceed as you did to find that $y=-1+Ce^{-x^2/2}$ where per construction $C\ne 0$ but $C=0$ reproduces the excluded constant solution, so no restrictions on $C$ are necessary.

If you want to confirm that in a more unified manner, use the method of the integrating factor which in this case is $e^{x^2/2}$ and from
$$
\left(e^{x^2/2}(y+1)\right)'=e^{x^2/2}(y'+x(y+1))=0
$$
you get again $e^{x^2/2}(y+1)=C$ without further restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar example here: 
[differential equation](http://[differential%20equation][1]https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240032/differential-equation-with-separable-probably-wrong-answer-in-book)

Could I exclude in similiar way solution $ y \neq 1 $, because $ln(0)$ dosen't exist in solution $ y = e^{c sin(x)} $ ?